# based on user input scroll dynamically using Win32 functions

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am writing a sample application similar to notepad using C & Win32 functions. As soon as the user press any key on key board it displays on the output as "Key Pressed: " and then move onto the next line. When the user continues to press key he will reach to the end of the page but i m finding it difficulty in scrolling the vertical bar dynamically.
I have even tried setting the scroll bar range dynamically using SetScrollInfo in WM_CHAR but still it does not work. Please suggest me a way to do this. Sample code for your reference.

```
    case WM_CHAR:
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        hdc = GetDC( hwnd );    
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        GetTextMetrics( hdc, &tm );
        cyChar = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        si.cbSize = sizeof( si );
        si.fMask  = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE;
        si.nMin   = 0;
        si.nMax   = iMaxLines;
        si.nPage  = cyClient / cyChar;
        SetScrollInfo( hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE );
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        wsprintf( szBuffer, TEXT("Key pressed %c, Pos: %d"), wParam, iMaxLines );
        TextOut( hdc, 0, cyChar * iMaxLines++, szBuffer, lstrlen( szBuffer ) );
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ReleaseDC( hwnd, hdc );
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        break;
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is necessary, but does your window have the WS_VSCROLL style?

Comment: yes...i have. Please find the code for window creation as below.

Comment: hwnd = CreateWindow( szClassName,
       TEXT("Text Pad"),
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WM_VSCROLL,
       CW_USEDEFAULT,
       CW_USEDEFAULT,
       CW_USEDEFAULT,
       CW_USEDEFAULT,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       hInstance,
       NULL );

 ShowWindow( hwnd, iCmdShow );
 UpdateWindow( hwnd );

Comment: That says *`WM_`* rather than *`WS_`*.

Comment: Yes...now i have modified it and re-executed the apps. It scrolls but i don't see any output on window as soon as it scrolls down.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're having a problem with: just managing the scrollbar position, or also scrolling the content? Note that the scrollbar does not actually do any scrolling for you; it's just a control that displays the thumb wherever you tell it to: you have to manage the scrolling in your client area yourself. So when you reach the bottom of the window, you need to move the rest of the content up (eg by redrawing), and somehow track of the fact that the window is now only displaying a portion of your overall contents (eg. have a variable that keeps track of what the top line is).

Comment: it seems really tough to implement this feature to me. :(

Comment: Check out Raymond Chens 12 (!) part series on scrollbars, it might be helpful. [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/07/23/54576.aspx), [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/07/25/54582.aspx) (the rest should be easy to find).

Comment: Best advice for you is to forget everything you think you know, get a copy of Petzold, and learn it all again properly.

Answer (score 2):

You are violating a pretty basic coding pattern in Windows: only draw stuff to the window in the WM_PAINT event handler.  Anything you draw elsewhere is not going to survive for long, the next repaint erases it.  Such as the one triggered by adjusting a scroll bar.

Simplify this coding task by using a list box.